# Trying to plot a line plot on a bar plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot a line plot over a bar plot using MatPlotLib. So far I have both the plots showing but I can't get a secondary y-axis with a different scale to work. When I try and put another one in it overwrites the original scale. My code is below

```
def hridef_base(x):
if x == 1:

    deltatlapexit = ExitSummary['Avg tLap'] - ExitSummary2['Avg tLap']

    plt.figure()
    index = (EntrySummary.index + 1)
    barwidth = 0.2

    plt.ylim(0.0, 65.0)
    plt.bar(index-barwidth, EntrySummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='r', yerr=EntrySummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Entry')
    plt.bar(index, ApexSummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='#4169E1', yerr=ApexSummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Apex')
    plt.bar(index+barwidth, ExitSummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='#32CD32', yerr=ExitSummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Exit')

    plt.plot(index, deltatlapexit, color='k', label='Entry')

    plt.xlabel('Turn Number')
    plt.ylabel('Average FRideH')
    plt.title('Average FRideH for Baseline setup')
    plt.xticks(index)
    plt.legend()

else:
    print "Baseline FRideH Not Selected"
```

Any advice on the matter is appreciated but please talk me through what to do instead of posting links to sites. I need to understand why I'm not able to do this.

Thank-you in advance. Please comment if I've missed anything out.

## UPDATE

Thanks to the comments below the graph now has two separate y-axis. How ever the y-label for the bar data has jumped to the right and if I try and plot the line y-label I get an Attribute error.

```
def hridef_base(x):
if x == 1:

    deltatlapexit = ExitSummary['Avg tLap'] - ExitSummary2['Avg tLap']

    fig, axis1 = subplots()
    index = (EntrySummary.index + 1)
    barwidth = 0.2

    axis1.ylim(0.0, 65.0)
    axis1.bar(index-barwidth, EntrySummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='r', yerr=EntrySummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Entry')
    axis1.bar(index, ApexSummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='#4169E1', yerr=ApexSummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Apex')
    axis1.bar(index+barwidth, ExitSummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='#32CD32', yerr=ExitSummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Exit')

    axis2 = axis1.twinx()
    axis2.set_ylim(-10.0, 10.0)
    axis2.plot(index, deltatlapexit, color='k', label='tDelta')

    axis1.xlabel('Turn Number')
    axis1.ylabel('Average FRideH')
    axis2.set_ylabel('tDelta')
    axis1.title('Average FRideH for Baseline setup')
    axis1.xticks(index)
    axis1.legend()
    axis2.legend()

else:
    print "Baseline FRideH Not Selected"
```

I would insert an image but I need 10 rep points...

The error I receive is:
    NameError: global name 'subplots' is not defined

Comment: Have you tried using [`twiny`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html)? Because otherwise, I don't see how you can adjust the scale of the secondary y-axis (as you mention).

Comment: I've looked at twiny a lot but I'm struggling to insert it into my code. A few pointers if you have experience would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be using explicit axis for your plotting (see http://matplotlib.org/users/artists.html#figure-container). Using `plt.ylabel` will change the last axis object you were working on. If you use `axis2.ylabel` this will set the label on the second axis. it will help to specify an axis handle for the first graph using `fig, axis1 = subplots()` and then use `axis1.bar` to plot your barcharts.

Comment: am I replacing plt.figure() with fig, axis1 = subplots() ?

Comment: 1/ Have you tried moving the `plt.ylabel` *before* the call to `twinx()`? 2/ How are trying to set the y-label for the twin-plot?

Comment: Updated to show what I've done. The problem is with the subplots bit. It's not recognizing it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't have your data, but using the [barplot example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) from matplotlib, here's an example with a bar plot and a line plot overplotted, with independently scaled y-axes:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure()          
N = 5
menMeans = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
menStd = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars
womenMeans = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
womenStd = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)    
ind = np.arange(N)
plt.ylim(0.0, 65.0)
plt.bar(ind, menMeans, width, color='r', yerr=menStd, label='Men means')
plt.bar(ind+width, womenMeans, width, color='y', yerr=womenStd, label='Women means')
plt.ylabel('Bar plot')      

x = np.linspace(0, N)
y = np.sin(x)
axes2 = plt.twinx()
axes2.plot(x, y, color='k', label='Sine')
axes2.set_ylim(-1, 1)
axes2.set_ylabel('Line plot')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You are a gent and a scholar sir! It has now plotted however the ylabel has jumped from the left to the right. If you could check back in a second when I've updated the question perhaps you could solve the new error?

Comment: Oh Evert you beautiful person you! It's done it perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

As a minimal example of what you need based on [this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html),

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup dummy data
N = 10
ind = np.arange(N)
bars = np.random.randn(N)
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)

#Plot graph with 2 y axes
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

#Plot bars
ax1.bar(ind, bars, alpha=0.3)
ax1.set_xlabel('$x$')

# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('bar', color='b')
[tl.set_color('b') for tl in ax1.get_yticklabels()]

#Set up ax2 to be the second y axis with x shared
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
#Plot a line
ax2.plot(t, np.sin(0.25*np.pi*t), 'r-')

# Make the y-axis label and tick labels match the line color.
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color='r')
[tl.set_color('r') for tl in ax2.get_yticklabels()]

plt.show()
```

which gives,
[image]

Comment: Thank-you very much! Combined with Evert I now have a working graph. The y-label is a bit problematic so once I've updated the question could you please advise?